# 2 services on same port on 2 different IP address on one physical server

Tags: ip, debian, iptables, nat

I have an OVH debian server with 2 IP addresses  :

- eth0      inet adr:5.39.78.122     (physical)
- eth0:0    inet adr:188.142.57.137  (failover)

I need to configure 2 different services on the same port 32 :

- One that will reply on 188.142.57.137:32
- The second one that will route 5.39.78.122:32 => 188.142.57.137:3232

I think that I can do it with iptables nat table but I don't know how to ?

Someone can explain me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks great !!! It works fine !!!

I used this tuto for first step setting Iptables :

https://wiki.debian.org/iptables

And add theses lines at the end :

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING --dst 5.39.78.122 -p tcp --dport 32 -j DNAT --to-destination 188.142.57.137:3232
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (assuming you mean TCP port 32):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst 5.39.78.122 -p tcp --dport 32 -j DNAT --to-destination 188.142.57.137:3232
```

If possible, I would try to bind the services to the specific adresses instead of using NAT. But this depends on your services.

Comment: Thanks it works fine, I will try to specify listening address in a second step.